# Django model field -- populate_from Option for CharField

Tags: django, django-models

Just wan't to ask if it is possible to use populate_from Option in a CharField field to prepopulate the field from other fields, just like the example of slug field.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ***name***= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='***name***', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

Let say,

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    eid= models.CharField(primary_key = True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

Now I wan't to add a new CharField fullname. I wan't the fullname to be populated from lastname, firstname and middlename fields.

```
fullname = models.CharField(populate_from = "***i don't know what to do here***")
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option that does not require overriding the `save` function:

```
class Employee(models.Model):

    def get_fullname(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.lastname, self.firstname, self.middlename)

    eid= models.CharField(primary_key = True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True) 
    fullname = property(get_fullname)
```

This option is great if you don't need to edit `fullname` separately from `lastname`, `firstname` and `middlename` as it does not display as a field in admin, but <s>stores the result in database</s> gets the value when called

Comment: is it ok with django rest?

Comment: if i edit the lastname, the fullname will be automatically modified?

Comment: It will be, yes. I just edited my answer, because this way `fullname` actually is not being stored in DB, but gets it's value when needed. Should also work fine with DRF, because `fullname` acts as regular field.

Comment: thanks for the reply man..sorry i can't up vote your answer. not enough reputation.. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the save method of the `Employee` model.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.fullname = '{0} {1} {2}'.format(self.firstname, self.middlename, self.lastname)
    super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For this you might have to keep `fullname` field as optional. Otherwise you may face error in forms.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution, **without populate_from**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    eid= models.CharField(primary_key = True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def save(self):
        self.fullname = "%s %s %s" % (lastname, firstname, middlename)
        super(Employee, self).save()
```

or with [AutoSlugField](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug) and **populate_from**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    eid= models.CharField(primary_key = True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    fullname = AutoSlugField(populate_from=lambda instance: instance.employee.get_full_name())

    def get_full_name(self):
        fullname = "%s %s %s" % (lastname, firstname, middlename)
        return fullname
```

Comment: thanks for the reply man, i will try this  as well as to the other answers. so that i have multiple options which to use..

Answer (score 1):

Use populate_from='name' in model:

```
class Menu(TimeStampedModel):
uuid = models.UUIDField(editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
parent = models.ForeignKey(
    'self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='childs'
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
link_base = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=500, populate_from='name', null=True, blank=True)
link_target = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, choices=LINK_TARGET_CHOICES)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```